# Use the $x(t)$ functions describing the motion of the two cars to predict where they will meet.

Tags: slope, related-rates

We have Car A and B, and I have the position of each car:

Car A:

$A= 1.374E2 *10^2$, $B= -2.719E2 *10^2$

$x= 1.374*10^2 -2.719*10^2...(1)$

Car B:

$A=6.473E2= 6.473*10^2, B=-4.402E2= -4.402*10^2 $

$x= 6.473*10^2t -4.402*10^2...(2)$

Use the $x(t)$ functions describing the motion of the two cars to predict where they will meet.

Graphs I drew in the tracker app:

Car A: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a10WA.png

Car B: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghO7j.png

This is the answer I got, but I think it's wrong. I need to find it in order to find where the two cars will meet.

One fast and one slow; two meters apart.

1.374*10^2 -2.719*10^2= 6.473*10^2t- 4.402*10^2 (1)

(6.473*10^2 -1.374*10^2)t= 4.402*10^2- 2.719*10^2 (2)

t= 4.402*10^2-2.719*10^2/ 6.473*10^2- 1.374*10^2= 0.33 seconds

Using any of equations

x= 1.374*10^2(0.33)-2.719*10^2

x= -226.55 m APART

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Please visit this [tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: I don't think the question has anything to do with graph theory; anyway, assume that at a time interval *T* the position function of Car A equals that of Car B. You'll obtain a polynomial equation in terms of *T*, solving for which gives possible values of *T*. Substitute *T* in the position function of either of the cars to get the answer.

Comment: Further, which physical parameters do *A* and *B* represent?

Comment: This is the answer I got, but I think it's wrong. 
One fast and one slow; two meters apart. 

1.374*10^2 -2.719*10^2= 6.473*10^2t- 4.402*10^2

(6.473*10^2 -1.374*10^2)t= 4.402*10^2- 2.719*10^2 

t= 4.402*10^2-2.719*10^2/ 6.473*10^2- 1.374*10^2= 0.33 s

Using any of equations

x= 1.374*10^2(0.33)-2.719*10^2


x= -226.55 m APART

Comment: hello! I just saw this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31368/532409 , maybe it is relevant since this question looks like something that should have the tag "homework" (not certainly "graph theory").

Comment: so you won't be able to lep me with this?